# Show that the set of rational numbers is $\textbf{dense}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Show that the set of rational numbers is $\textbf{dense}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that every real number is a limit of rational numbers. Wrote a proof, wondering if it's correct/rigorous enough and if not, where it goes wrong.

So we seek to show that given a $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists$ a sequence of rational numbers $a_n$, $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = x$.

By the definition of convergence, we know this means that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq N \implies |a_n - x| < \epsilon$.

Which we can rewrite as $x - \epsilon < a_n < x + \epsilon$.

By the Archimedean property, we know in $\mathbb{R}, \forall\ x < y \in \mathbb{R}, \exists\ r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x < r < y$. Since $x - \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x + \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, we know there exists a $r \in \mathbb{Q}, x - \epsilon < r < x + \epsilon$. So we know $\exists$ such an $a_n$.

Comment: How about the sequence given by the decimal expansion of a real number $x?$

Comment: Your solution is ok.

Comment: The proof depends on your definition of $\mathbb{R}$: is it the metric completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ (as Cantor did) or is the order-completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ (as Dedekind did, using his eponymous cuts)? Or some other naïve approach using decimal expansions (hopefully not)? In the former cases, the density of the rationals is true by construction.

Comment: It is curious... density of $D$ in $X$ is usually defined by simply requiring that between any two elements of $X$ there is one of $D$. Under this usual definition, you already have that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Construction I learned was the approach using decimal expansions / infinite decimals.